# How to add a new field to database (with default value)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I’ve started learning Ruby on Rails recently. I did a blogger tutorial. I want to add one more field archive to my database, but not sure is it possible just to write manually and which command to call?
Here is my database where I want to add code:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to add a new field archive which is boolean and by default false?
Also is it okay to add in this schema new field or is it better in some other?

Answer (score 3):

1.Run the migration from command line to add the new column

```
$ rails g migration add_column_archive_to_articles archive:boolean
```

The above command will create a new migration file in your `db/migrate` folder.

2.As of now there's no option to add default value to a column, which can be defined through terminal. Set the new column value to `true/false` by editing the new migration file created. Your migration file will look like this.

```
class AddColumnArchiveToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :archive, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

3.Then do

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Migrations should never be changed afterwords. That is why they are migrations, and not a static schema definitions.

Just generate a new migration using `rails g migration AddArchiveToArticles` and then check the rails documentation for `add_column` to see how you can alter a table to add a column. It also supports default values :)